# Ball physics: Controlling ball velocity with direction

Tags: c++, directx, game-physics

How do I implement a ball shooting upwards from ground height at a certain angle?

I have tried applying in the `ball->update(frameTime)`

```
    velocity.x  = cos(tank->getAngle()) * baseSpeed;
    velocity.y  = sin(tank->getAngle()) * baseSpeed;
    spriteData.x += velocity.x * frameTime;
    spriteData.y += velocity.y * frameTime;
```

But the ball just randomly flies and going out of game screen.

Help?

Comment: Does `getAngle` return degrees or radians?  Does the `sin` and `cos` functions you are using expect degrees or radians?

Comment: @George tank->getAngle() is the angle of the barrel which is relative to the tank

Comment: @NathanOliver it returns degrees, cos and sin uses radians, but i've tried changes getAngle to radians and it still does not work

Comment: @user7194060 Are you using some sort of math library or is it all your own? Either way, it's a goof idea to implement or use a `Vector` class it makes stuff like this trivial, i.e. `Vector toTarget = (target - currentPos).normalize; currentPos += toTarget * speed * dt * gravity/*if not applied somewhere else*/;`

Comment: @George what do i put as my target? i'm trying to shoot the ball freely into the air with no intended x,y.

Comment: @user7194060 it doesn't matter ( it's normalized into a direction and so long as gravity is applied will eventually fall, and you can do whatever you want to speed i.e. decelerate ), just anywhere along the straight of the barrel, i.e. mosuepos. I guess a better name for `toTarget` maybe `dir`

Comment: @George if thats the case, what's do i initialise my target as? I'm just using a keyboard to control the angle of the barrel, hence the non-controlled target. really do appreciate your guidance.

Comment: If you really do only have the angle you can do `Vector toTarget( cos(tank->getAngle()/pi ), sin(tank->getAngle()/pi) );` where the first argument is x and second y. <- This does _not_ need to be normalized and you can still use `currentPos += toTarget * speed * dt * gravity/*if not applied somewhere else*/;`. But if the tank is aiming at literally anything, i.e. a cursor, you can normalize that objects position and ( find the diff between currentPos and target ) it will give you the exact same result as `Vector toTarget( cos(tank->getAngle()/pi ), sin(tank->getAngle()/pi) );`

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments of the video it appears there's a misunderstanding. I think when George said use the toTarget vector he means it as the gradient of the line of travel of the ball. Not the balls actual final destination. also the conversion from degrees to radians would be

```
((Tank->getangle()*pi)/180).
```

In not vector form:

(POSSIBLE WRONG SYNTAX BUT THE MATH IS CORRECT)

```
velocity.x  = cos((Tank->getangle()*pi)/180) * baseSpeed;
velocity.y  = sin((Tank->getangle()*pi)/180) * baseSpeed;
spriteData.x += velocity.x * frameTime;
spriteData.y += velocity.y * frameTime;
```

also I'm but sure what your frameTime variable is but it could be causing you problems if it works the way I'm imagining its working from its name. if your programme still isn't working when you read this it could very well be to do with that.